# $_POST or $_REQUEST returns undefined even if it is normal page request not POST

Tags: php

I am new to php. i have already worked on asp.net mvc, now learning php.

I have studied $_POST and $_REQUEST and tried to use it as:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="test" action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method='post' >
            <input type='text' name='abc'>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <?php
        // put your code here
        $abc = $_POST["abc"];
        echo abc;
        $abc = $_REQUEST["abc"];
        echo abc;
        ?>



    </body>
</html>
```

but when i run these lines are comming :

Notice: Undefined index: abc in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\index.php on line 20

Notice: Use of undefined constant abc - assumed 'abc' in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\index.php on line 21
abc

[image]

Comment: abc is a var, prefix with $ signal

Comment: are you running it in any web server or just opening the file in a web browser

Comment: @Satya The user get PHP `Notice` errors in web page, so he is running in web server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="test" action='' method='post' >
            <input type='text' name='abc'>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <?php
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
            echo $_POST["abc"];;
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Since you post to same page address is not necessary a PHP_SELF. Also, you must access $_POST index vars after form submit

Answer (score 1):

`abc` is a variable, you wrote:

```
echo abc;
```

This should be:

```
echo $abc;
```

Answer (score 1):

when you load it first time that are undefined so check through `isset`

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST["abc"]))
        {
          $abc = $_POST["abc"];
          echo $abc;
        }

        if(isset($_REQUEST["abc"]))
        {
          $abc = $_REQUEST["abc"];
          echo $abc;
        }
        ?>
```